# jQuery.ajax post working on local machine but getting 404 on vps which is using SSL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, https

I'm coding a Wordpress website that takes form input, validates it through jquery then sends it via ajax-post to another file in my theme for processing. It works perfectly fine in my local machine, but when I transferred it to my vps, it began to give me 404s for the .php file that's supposed to process the post data.

Here is the relevant code:

```
postData = new FormData;
postData.append('field', data);

 jQueenter code herery.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "/wp-content/themes/theme-name/make-post.php",
                        data: postData,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,

                        success: function(data){
                            //Do Stuff
                            }); 
                        }
```

});

It gives me an error saying that make-post.php is 404 not found.

I'm new to using VPS and HTTPS and I also noticed that I can't use hardcoded urls for referencing images or other resources, they always give me 404 errors. I managed to get around this by using bloginfo('url/template_url') wp functions but am at a loss for how to do this for my .js file which is doing the ajax request.

Comment: Have you tried to use a full URL instead?

Comment: I think I figured it out, my local machine is windows and the server is linux, and while my file paths were working case insensitive on windows the same wasn't true when the files hit the server. T_T I tested it out on a hunch and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, my local machine is windows and the server is linux, and while my file paths were working case insensitive on windows the same wasn't true when the files hit the server. T_T I tested it out on a hunch and it started working